# jvisualvm is not working with eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, memory-management, visualvm, jvisualvm

For who knows what is the jvisualvm, I downloaded a plugin to eclipse to initiate the application with the jvisualvm. But unlike the official site says, when I run any java application, the program does NOT appear in the left side. There's only one global tab.

Any clues?

Comment: Why not run VisualVM standalone?

Comment: yea, I could do that too hehe. But still the same problem. Only one global application appear. Not others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you running the java application as the same user? I seem to recall that by default it only sees processes started by the same userid.

Comment: oh, problem solved. Thanks Kevin. Your informations helped me to see that I was running in a machine which I was not administrator :o